# Getting an “you must upgrade Azure CLI” error when attempting to run Enterprise Bot Template in Visual Studio 2017 but my Azure CLI is up to date

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-cli

I’m trying to deploy the Enterprise Bot Template using VS 2017 and I got the following error when running the `msbot clone services` code in the ReadMe file.

```
C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\SovereignBot\SovereignBot>msbot clone services --name "SovereignBot" --luisAuthoringKey "2c92b0812f6b47cfa5d4da293f2bbaa3" --folder "DeploymentScripts\en" --location "westus"
```

> With msbot 4.3.2 and later, the only AZ CLI prerequisite is having an AZ CLI version >= 2.0.53. If you have the botservice extension installed as well, please remove this via "az extension remove --name botservice". Checking az botservice version You need to upgrade your AZ CLI version to >= 2.0.53. You can install the latest AZ CLI from https://aka.ms/az-cli-download

My version of [MSBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/tree/master/packages/MSBot) is 4.3.2 and I’mm on the latest version of [Azure CLI (2.0.58)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/962) with `msbot`.

There's currently [a Pull Request](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/pull/963) to fix it, so keep an eye out for a new `msbot` version.

For now, you have to downgrade to any AZ CLI v2.0.53 through v2.0.57.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mdricardson. Seems that fix sorts me out...It worked!